# Is there a way to select an element by class even though the class has been removed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, function

At the start I don't want .screen-text-page2 visibile, only after .screen-text-button-page1 is clicked

```js
$('.screen-text-page2').removeClass("screen-text-page2");

$('.screen-text-button-page1').click(function() {
  $('.screen-text-page2').addClass("screen-text-page2");
});
```

```css
.screen-text-page2 {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="screen-text-button-page1">Button</button>

<div class="screen-text-page2">Div with class screen-text-page2</div>
```

Comment: No. The selector inside your click handler callback function seeks matching elements when the function is called. The class would have to be present _then_. I suggest you ask about your overall goal instead. Maybe we can help you find a solution.

Comment: So why are you not adding something to hide it?

Comment: Logically this doesn't make much sense. Better give your div an ID and reference that instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes

The removeClass method is not a state... once you run it the class is removed and the element can accept any new class, including the same one.

If you want to re-add the class, then just add it again.

```
$("#ele").removeClass(".myClass");
$("#ele").addClass(".myClass");
```

is completely valid

Comment: This isn't the same scenario. See the snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but because you're removing the class, you won't be able to select it again via `$('.screen-text-page2')`. But if you save the selected element as a variable, you can reference it again without needing to reselect it using the class.

```js
let page2 = $('.screen-text-page2');
$(page2).removeClass("screen-text-page2");

$('.screen-text-button-page1').click(function() {
  $(page2).addClass("screen-text-page2");
});
```

```css
.screen-text-page2 {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="screen-text-button-page1">Button</button>

<div class="screen-text-page2">Div with class screen-text-page2</div>
```

Another way to do something like this is to add another class before removing `.screen-text-page2`, and then reselecting the element using this placeholder class. But in my opinion, that's just more steps than the above example.

```js
$('.screen-text-page2').addClass("screen-text-page2-placeholder");
$('.screen-text-page2').removeClass("screen-text-page2");

$('.screen-text-button-page1').click(function() {
  $('.screen-text-page2-placeholder').addClass("screen-text-page2");
});
```

```css
.screen-text-page2 {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="screen-text-button-page1">Button</button>

<div class="screen-text-page2">Div with class screen-text-page2</div>
```